# Submit an ajax-created form via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having trouble getting an ajax-loaded form (#ajaxLoadedForm) to submit via ajax. The formData object gathers no data. I figure I've got to attach an event-handler to the form so the DOM recognizes it, but I can't figure out how.

A couple of notes: I'm bypassing the 'submit' method and using a button (#button), so I can't attach the handler to that. The form itself is a sibling to #button, not a child.

```
<form id="ajaxLoadedForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="destination.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="1" />
<label for="fullname">Your Full Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="fullname" placeholder="your name" value="" />
</form>
<div id="button">Submit me!</div>

$('#button').click(function(){
    var uploadData = new FormData($("#ajaxLoadedForm")[0]);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'destination.php',
        data: uploadData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data['pass'] == false) {
                console.log('fail');
            } else {
                console.log('success');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This is pointless. Show your html form!

Comment: Just added it. The inputs themselves aren't really relevant but I can go back in and flesh it out. Just trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the submit handler on the form itself

```
$('#ajaxLoadedForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var uploadData = new FormData(this);
});
```

Then make your button for submit a submit type

```
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
```

In your php side, test the data coming by doing this:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: I tried a number of other things and this was the only thing that worked. In order to attach a handle I had had to move my submission action so it was a child of the form and change it to a 'submit' type, then preventDefault when it fired. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use serialize function for sending form data . Like below

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
$('#button').click(function(){
    var uploadData = $('#ajaxLoadedForm').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'destination.php',
        data: uploadData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
           data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data['pass'] == false) {
                console.log('fail');
            } else {
                console.log('success');
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
$('#button').click(function(){
var uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('fullName',$('#fullName').val());

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'destination.php',
    data: uploadData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

    }
});

});
```

And try to access full name in php